# Microsoft Azure Symbolic Link Storage folder Laravel

Tags: laravel, azure, laravel-5, cmd, azure-web-app-service

I am using laravel 5.3 on Microsoft Azure web server...

I am having an issue creating a symbolic link between my /public/storage/ and /storage/app/public/ folders

I do not have the required permissions to create a symbolic link, and I have also tried to use the following command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Which automatically creates a symbolic link, however it gives the error:

> Access is denied.

I have tried to also run the command:

```
mklink /d "D:home\site\wwwroot\storage\app\public\" "D:home\site\wwwroot\public\storage\"
```

And the error is something along the lines of:

> You do not have sufficient privileges to perform this operation

How can I run command prompt in Microsoft Azure in elevated administrator mode so that I can actually create a symbolic link...

Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Creating symlinks is something that is blocked by the Azure Web App sandbox. You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#symbolic-link-creation).

If you consist to create symlinks, you can try to leverage Azure VMs.